# Is this the correct community to ask questions on style and procedure, rather than specific questions begging as specific answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-definition

I would like to gather opinions on matters of style, organization, and procedure related to software development.  As an example, I'm looking for the right place to ask something like the following:

> What are best practices for organizing code inside a Visual Studio web application?
>
> I have a /js folder in which I keep various .js modules (startupCode.js, ajaxCalls.js, etc), and I link them in the header of my index.html.  But if I gather all js scripts into one large .js file, I end up linking in a lot of code that isn't going to be pertinent to some given task.  But if I split them out into separate modules, I may end up having dozens and dozens of modules.  Where's the common ground on organizing js code?

I've learned (the hard way ;-) not to ask something like that on Stack Overflow, so I'm looking for the right place.

Comment: Are you asking a question here, or asking whether you should ask your question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making "best practices" questions more palatable: how to ask a "best practice" question that is acceptable to the community?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/making-best-practices-questions-more-palatable-how-to-ask-a-best-practice-q)

Comment: My apologies.  I followed a link from a meta conversation to that forum, which was suggested as the place to ask such a question.  I thought I was still in the meta site.  My bad.

Answer (score 5):

We have the same rules as Stack Overflow as to [the types of questions that we don't allow here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - no chatty, open-ended questions; no questions that require a book to answer; no discussions; no poll questions where every answer is equally valid; no questions without an actual problem; no rants.

We also have some guidance as to [how to ask a good question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - [be on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); search (the broader Internet and previously asked questions here); be specific with details and contexts, but make it relevant to the broader community.

Going to your specific case - I'm sure we have other questions here about organizing code. We probably even have questions about organizing web application code. Maybe even in Visual Studio. Search those and read them. If, for some reason, those don't answer your question, feel free to describe your problem. Demonstrate that you've done your research (link to things that you've read, for example). And say why the things that you've found aren't helpful to you. If you do those, then you probably have a good question here.

One note - we tend [not to like "best practice" questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/making-best-practices-questions-more-palatable-how-to-ask-a-best-practice-q). A ["best practice is a method or technique that has been generally accepted as superior to any alternatives because it produces results that are superior to those achieved by other means or because it has become a standard way of doing things"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice). That simply means that it works for most people most of the time. We'd rather tell you about the right practice for your case. Chances are, you aren't the only one in a similar situation that the so-called "best practice" doesn't work for. Your question may help people understand options and why things may or may not be the right thing to do.